# Remote permission denied in github while trying to push to origin

Tags: github, git-commit, git-push, git

I have started to contribute to a public repository on GitHub, but after I have created a pull request it says remote: Permission when I am trying to push another code to my origin.

> remote: Permission to una/CSSgram.git denied to Pradhvan.
>  fatal:
>   unable to access 'https://github.com/una/CSSgram.git/': The requested
>   URL returned error: 403

Comment: You cannot directly push to random repositories unless you are a owner / collaborator with push permissions.

Comment: @PeeHaa i created a PR to this repo and later when i was trying to post another code up i got this error .

Comment: We have no idea what "trying to post another code " means.

Comment: Once your PR is merged, you can not directly collaborate with the source repository. You can only push to your fork and create new PRs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyone else having the same problem. The issue would be you had cloned the repo from Github of the owner(here Una's repo) and you are pushing that change directly to the repo. This is the not right way as you don't have permission to push changes to that repo.

The right step would be:

1. Fork the original repo so you get a copy of it. Url of your forked repo would be something like `https://github.com/<your Github username>/<repo_name>`
2. Clone the repo that you just forked.
3. Create a branch (`git checkout -b "MyPatch1"`) and now make the changes to the code.
4. Push the changes to your fork (`git push origin MyPatch1`)
5. Open Github and go to the owner's repo and you would see a button appear Click the *Compare & pull request button*.

Congratulation! You have successfully created a pull request.